# append "," before each capital letter of string

Tags: java, regex

I need to append `,` before each capital letter of string. Should I use regex or `split`?

Example:

```
String s = "TonyRoyTroyMagic";
```

I want the output to be like

`"Tony,Roy,Troy,Magic"`

Comment: you need to show some research efforts first

Comment: Why not use a simple loop?

Answer (score 1):

Using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

```
String s = "TonyRoyTroyMagic";
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Z]", ",$0");   
System.out.println(s); // Tony,Roy,Troy,Magic
```

---

### Explaination

`?<=` is a lookbehind to check if the capital letter `[A-Z]` at least has `[A-Za-z0-9]` behind. It will prevent from putting a comma as the first character of the string.

In the example you showed, the following is also valid

```
(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]
```

Comment: Thanks ,What if i have blank space in between("TonyRoy Troy Magic")?

Comment: It'll print `Tony,Roy,Troy ,Magic`

Comment: Actually here i am taking command line input so every blank space increases the array index.

Comment: @user6118413 What do you mean? Is that a problem?

Comment: No its working fine. But when i am taking command line input like "TonyRoy Troy Magic"-public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = args[0];// Assigning command line input to string
  s = s.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Z]", ",$0");
  System.out.println(s);

 }

}

Comment: Yes now  i have the expected result,Thanks :)

Comment: @user6118413 Feel free to mark the answer as accepted than :) And upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over string and create new one like this:

```
   String S = "TonyRoyTroyMagic";
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0;i<S.length();i++ ) {
        char c = S.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c) && i != 0 ) {
            sb.append(",");
        }
        sb.append(c);
   }
   System.out.println(sb.toString());
   //result: Tony,Roy,Troy,Magic
```